# How many roles and profile can be assigned to a user in salesforce

Tags: profile, roles

what is the limitation for number of roles and profile that can be assigned to a user in salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A user can only have a single **Profile** and **Role** assigned to them. The screenshot below shows the Edit User screen where you can set the **Profile** and **Role**

[image: Profile and Role]

Another option to grant permissions to multiple users are [Permission Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm). Multiple Permission Sets can be granted to each user

You can also use [Public Groups](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=user_groups.htm&language=en_US) rather than Roles if you want to group users together. A user could be in multiple Public Groups.